# Cannot connect to uninitialized Replica Set with the Go driver

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-replica-set

I'm trying to connect to a member of a future replica set in order to initiate the replica set with `replSetInitiate` using the official Go mongodb driver (not mgo).

I can connect fine to my instance using the mongodb shell but the same connection string does not work with the go driver. The go driver returns a server selection timeout.

I tried setting the `Direct` parameter to true on the client options object but that gives me an unauthenticated error on the first command I try to run. Again, I have no issues with authentication in the mongodb shell, the authentication works properly.

The connection string looks like `mongodb://admin:password@host`.

It seems to me like the problem is that the go driver tries to connect to what should be a working replica set, but it hasn't been initialized yet. Is there a way of preventing this behavior of the Go mongodb driver?

Comment: Show us da codez! ;) Of special importance would be our code to initialize the replset.